# Django hosted deployment (like Heroku/ep.io) that supports Java?

Tags: django, heroku, cloud-hosting

Are there any hosted deployment services (like Heroku or ep.io) that allow java workers (I have a java web service internally) AND which have EEA datacenters? (for those that don't know, for legal reasons, businesses in the EEA face significant restrictions on moving data outside the EEA).

Answer (score 0):

I guess the answer will probably be found at: http://djangofriendly.com - a list of reviews of django hosting options.